# Has tilde notation superseded the e function in less?

Tags: less

Has tilde notation superseded the `e` function in less? Per the [docs e function](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e):

> CSS escaping, replaced with ~"value" syntax.

If it has been, how does one do the following with tilde notation? It doesn't seem possible.

`e()` works

```
@screen-lg-dim: 1024;
@screen-lg: e(%("only screen and (min-width: %spx)", @screen-lg-dim));
```

`~()` does not:

```
@screen-lg-dim: 1024;
@screen-lg: ~(%("only screen and (min-width: %spx)", @screen-lg-dim));
// error
```

Comment: Technically it did not. It's just a sight oversimplification of  the docs. Both features overlap but not 100% interchangeable. For your example though the right syntax would be: `%(~"%apx", @bar);` ([demo](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22y%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%40bar%3A%201024%3B%5Cn%20%20foo%3A%20%25(~%5C%22%25apx%5C%22%2C%20%40bar)%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D)).. Also the `e` function is not depracated and won't be ` so if it does the trick it's nothing wrong with having it in a code.

Comment: Also note that for this example the `%` function is an overkill. What you need there is just trivial variable ["interpolation"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation): `~"... @{bar}px ...";`

Comment: @seven-phases-max your comments are perfectly acceptable as an answer if you want points! :)

Comment: I know, feel free to compose the answer yourself (I'm just too lazy to make answers that could fit my own rather high perfectionist standards).